# Query MongoDB search only in specific hours

Tags: node.js, mongodb

i have a question, i want to search by specific hours of the day,

Lets start:

My data schema sees like this:

```
{
 "symbol": "Orange",
 "timestamp": ISODate("2016-05-01T20:00:00.000Z"),
 "price": 10
}
```

I have a lot of entries, and the value of price change minute by minute.

If i want to search, let's say, all days when the hours of the day are: 9 or 15, so the result must return all the entries 9 to 9:59 and 15 to 15:59

I try to do something like:

```
 { $match: { timestamp: { $hour: { $in: [array_hours] } } }
```

But obviously, don't work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think you can use $hour, $day ... to break down the date in aggregation.
For example:

my data:

```
db.orders.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5760bf21b05d6825e05fa23d"), "item" : "test1", 
          "create_at" : ISODate("2016-04-30T11:00:00Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5760bf30b05d6825e05fa23e"), "item" : "test2", 
          "create_at" : ISODate("2016-04-30T12:00:00Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5760bf37b05d6825e05fa23f"), "item" : "test3",  
          "create_at" : ISODate("2016-04-30T13:00:00Z") }
```

my query:

```
db.orders.aggregate([{$project:{hour:{$hour:"$create_at"}}}, 
                 {$match:{hour:{"$in":[11,12]}}}])
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5760bf21b05d6825e05fa23d"), "hour" : 11 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5760bf30b05d6825e05fa23e"), "hour" : 12 }
```

[Here is the doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/hour/)

Comment: This is exactly what im looking for, thanks! you are awasome!, thanks for your time, realy.

Comment: This saved my day. How would I have to modify this to run on only create_at > '2021-01-01'?

Answer (score 1):

please see mongo shell query below as it utilises power of  aggregation framework with simple per hour analitics:

**this will produce following output:**

```
{
    "_id" : {
        "year" : 2016,
        "month" : 5,
        "day" : 1,
        "hour" : 20
    },
    "avgPrice" : 10.5,
    "min" : 10.0,
    "max" : 11.0,
    "firstEntryValue" : 10.0,
    "lastEntrValue" : 11.0,
    "allEntries" : [ 
        {
            "timestamp" : ISODate("2016-05-01T20:00:00.000Z"),
            "value" : 10.0,
            "_id" : ObjectId("57610dce41bcea24b9792443")
        }, 
        {
            "timestamp" : ISODate("2016-05-01T20:01:00.000Z"),
            "value" : 11.0,
            "_id" : ObjectId("57610dd641bcea24b9792444")
        }, 
        {
            "timestamp" : ISODate("2016-05-01T20:01:03.000Z"),
            "value" : 10.0,
            "_id" : ObjectId("57610dde41bcea24b9792445")
        }, 
        {
            "timestamp" : ISODate("2016-05-01T20:01:05.000Z"),
            "value" : 11.0,
            "_id" : ObjectId("57610de341bcea24b9792446")
        }
    ]
}
```

> query example

```
var projectTime = {
    $project : {
        _id : 1,
        symbol : 1,
        price : 1,
        timestamp : 1,
        // now we need to add year/month/day/hour
        // having this field as separate ones will help us to have diffrent groupping options
        year : {
            $year : "$timestamp"
        },
        month : {
            $month : "$timestamp"
        },
        day : {
            $dayOfMonth : "$timestamp"
        },
        hour : {
            $hour : "$timestamp"
        },
    }
}

var group = {
    $group : {
        _id : {
            year : "$year",
            month : "$month",
            day : "$day",
            hour : "$hour"
        },
        avgPrice : {
            $avg : "$price"
        },
        min : {
            $min : "$price"
        },
        max : {
            $max : "$price"
        },
        firstEntryValue : {
            $first : "$price"
        },
        lastEntrValue : {
            $last : "$price"
        },
        allEntries : {
            $push : {
                timestamp : "$timestamp",
                value : "$price",
                _id : "$_id"
            }
        },

    }
}

db.casy.aggregate([projectTime, group])
```

Comment: Hi @profesor79, thanks for your response, was realy usefull, you help me to make the perfect query, thanks for your time! realy apreciate it.